# Why is $\mathbf{Rel} \cong \mathbf{Rel}^{\mathbb{op}}$?

Tags: category-theory

I haven't yet fully grasped Category Theory so I am doing the exercises in Awodey's book for the first chapter, and exercise 2a) is confusing me very much.

The question is to prove or disprove that $\mathbf{Rel} \cong \mathbf{Rel}^{\mathbf{op}}$. I get that the idea is 
$$f^{\mathbf{op}}: D \longrightarrow C = \{\langle d,c \rangle \in D\times C| (c,d) \in f\}$$

But I can't write the functor because according to the definition: $$F(f:C\longrightarrow D)=F(f):F(C)\longrightarrow F(D)$$

So if there are two relations from $C$ to different objects, $F(C)$ would not be defined.

What am I doing/understanding wrong? Thank you!

edit: I should add that I say $\mathbf{Rel} \cong \mathbf{Rel}^{\mathbb{op}}$ not because I proved it but because I read a document with the solutions...

Comment: $F$ is supposed to be a contravariant functor. So it sends a relation $C \to D$ to a relation $D \to C$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I understand what you say, but to me it doesn't fit the definition of functor I've been given: Mapping from objects to objects and arrows to arrows in such a way that: $F(f:C\longrightarrow D)=F(f):F(C)\longrightarrow F(D)$, $F(f\circ g) = F(f)\circ F(g)$, and $F(1_A)=1_{F(A)}$. This is the definition I use (1st chapter, Awodey) and as you see it says nothing about contravariance...

Comment: @ZhenLin Actually, it's not necessary to do that. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the problems with these exercises in Awodey is that he didn't actually define "isomorphism of categories" in the first chapter. But let us take it to mean "isomorphism in $\sf Cat$", the category of (small) categories and functors.

In the preceding exercise, one is asked to show that:

$$C: {\sf Rel}^{\rm op} \to {\sf Rel}$$

given as the identity on objects, and on relations as $C(R^{\rm op}: D^{\rm op} \to C^{\rm op}) = R^c: D \to C$ (note that $R^{\rm op}:D^{\rm op} \to C^{\rm op}$ corresponds to $R: C \to D$ in $\sf Rel$) is a functor.

Let us check the composition property of $C$ on $S^{\rm op}: E^{\rm op}\to D^{\rm op}$ and $R^{\rm op}$:

\begin{align}
C(S^{\rm op}R^{\rm op}) &= C((RS)^{\rm op}) & &\text{Definition of composition in $\sf Rel^{\rm op}$}\\
&= (RS)^c & &\text{Definition of $C$}\\
&= \{(e,c) \mid (c,e) \in RS\} &&\text{Definition of $(-)^c$}\\
&= \{(e,c)\mid \exists d \in D: (c,d)\in R, (d,e)\in S\} &&\text{Definition of $RS$}\\
&= \{(e,c)\mid \exists d \in D: (d,c)\in R^c, (e,d) \in S^c\}\\
&= S^c R^c = C(S^{\rm op})C(R^{\rm op})
\end{align}

It's not hard now to verify that $C$ is indeed a functor. I'm sure you can define a functor $C^{\rm op}: {\sf Rel}\to {\sf Rel}^{\rm op}$ that together with $C$ gives ${\sf Rel} \cong {\sf Rel}^{\rm op}$.

As a general advice, I suggest that you meticulously write the $\rm op$ superscript on every object and morphism in an opposite category until you know your way around. This can help to overcome some of the initial confusion.

Comment: I do _not_ recommend this practice as it can be rather confusing in a category that has an involution, such as $\mathbf{Poset}$.

Comment: I think part of my confusion came, as you say, from not writing the $\rm op$ everywhere (the idea of formally turning arrows around is a bit weird to me). I understood isomorphism as you say, is there another way? I will do the same for $C$ and see if I can! Thank you

Comment: @Duronman It's just that he doesn't define it (and $\sf Rel$ is not an object of $\sf Cat$). Later on, you'll get to know about *equivalence* of categories, which sort of amounts to "isomorphic up to isomorphism" and which is in many cases more useful.

Comment: @ZhenLin Indeed. It is a practice mostly useful to get to know your way around opposite categories. Specific applications may be more insightful without the $\rm op$s.